# Transforming JSON array into JS array

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, parsing

I have a list of objects coming from a JSON file, and need it to be stored as an array of objects in JS.

This would be my JSON:

```
   [
     {"id":"1","name":"abc"},
     {"id":"2","name":"pqr"},
     {"id":"3","name":"xyz"}
   ]
```

I need it to be inside a variable in JS, like this:

```
let data = [
     {"id":"1","name":"abc"},
     {"id":"2","name":"pqr"},
     {"id":"3","name":"xyz"}
   ];
```

I'm trying to use JQuery:

```
$.getJSON('json', function(data) {
    plates = $.parseJSON(data);
 });
```

But I'm getting the following error:

VM464:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at Function.parse [as parseJSON]

For what I've seen, I may already have the object, not needing the parse function. Is that the reason?

**The second problem in the code**

I'm using the array in a map function:

```
data.map(data_item) => {
   //function
}
```

But I'm gettind the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Why is that?

Comment: You probably don't need to parse JSON. $.getJSON already gives you data as a javascript array, not a string you'll need to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reading The JSON

`jQuery.getJSON` sends an http request to retrieve json from a server. You should only use it when you need to get json from a server (over the internet), it is no good for reading it from a file. In fact, client side javascript does not have access to a file system at all. This means that if your web browser is running code it cannot read from any files on the computer unless your user specifically uploads a file using an `<input/>` element.

So, if you would like the user to be able to upload a `.json` file and then read that into a javascript object, you can do this in your html:

```
<input type="file" id="upload">
```

And then do this in your javascript:

```
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', readFile)
function readFile() {
    // This will run any time a file is selected or deselected.
    var files = this.files;
    if (files.length === 0) {
        console.log('No file is selected');
        return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        // This is where you are given access to the file as a string. Convert the string to json...
        const fileText = event.target.result; // The text is stored in event.target.result
        const object = JSON.parse(event.target.result); // Parse the text as json
    };
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

If you did in fact want to get JSON from a server then you can use `$.getJSON` except you do not need to parse the data afterwards. The first parameter you pass to `getJSON` should never be `'json'`, it should be the URL of the json you want to retrieve:

```
$.getJSON('https://fakewebsite.com/api/data/get', function(data) {
    // here data is already json.
 });
```

## 'Map' of undefined

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`
You're calling `.map` on `data`, and `data` is undefined. `data` needs to be an array for you to use map. If you correctly set the value of `data` to be an array it will begin to work.

Assuming that you did what I said above, and you upload a file using the input and that file's text is a JSON array, you can now do:

```
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', readFile)
function readFile() {
    // This will run any time a file is selected or deselected.
    var files = this.files;
    if (files.length === 0) {
        console.log('No file is selected');
        return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        const fileText = event.target.result;
        const array = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
        array.map((data_item)=>{
            //function
        });
    };
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}
```

Your `.map` function also was incorrect syntax. Instead you need a set of parenthesis around the inline function like I did above:

```
data.map((data_item) => {
   //function
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Really clarified some doubts I had! I was trying the JSON as a response from the server, and with its data use the map function to display them in the html page. My problem was in the map function, which I was using outside the getJSON one.